# Go generate some Java

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Your boss wants you to write code like this:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
    input == 1L
  || input == 10L
  || input == 100L
  || input == 1000L
  || input == 10000L
  || input == 100000L
  || input == 1000000L
  || input == 10000000L
  || input == 100000000L
  || input == 1000000000L
  || input == 10000000000L
  || input == 100000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000L
  || input == 10000000000000L
  || input == 100000000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000000L
  || input == 10000000000000000L
  || input == 100000000000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000000000L;
}
```

(Martin Smith, at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/117294/61929)

which is efficient and so, but not that fun to type. Since you want to minimize the number of keypresses you have to do, you write a shorter program or function (or method) that outputs this function for you (or returns a string to output). And since you have your [very own custom full-range unicode keyboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AtBE9BOvvk) with all 120,737 keys required for all of unicode 8.0, we count unicode characters, instead of keypresses. Or bytes, if your language doesn't use unicode source code.

Any input your program or function takes counts towards your score, since you obviously have to type that in as well.

Clarifications and edits:

- Removed 3 trailing spaces after the last `}`
- Removed a single trailing space after `return`
- Returning a string of output from a function/method is ok

Comment: `0==Math.log10(input)%1`

Comment: You say "*we count unicode characters*," but then you immediately say "*Or bytes*." Which one is it?

Comment: Whichever you prefer, i.e. the one that gives you the lowest score. Added bytes to allow languages that don't use text source.

Comment: `while(input%10==0) input/=10; return input == 1;`

Comment: @FilipHaglund Your comment seems to make the scoring a little unfair. I could write a program in bytecode, and say its unicode to shave off a few bytes... Maybe you meant what you stated in the question; that you should only count in unicode if your program is written in it?

Comment: I don't want to exclude languages that don't use unicode, or languages that do use unicode. Do you have a suggested edit to the rules? It doesn't seem like anyone has used unicode yet in an answer.

Comment: @FilipHaglund The 05AB1E answer uses unicode.  Unless I am wildly mistaken and "Æ£‹ÒŒ€" isn't unicode (answer was posted 4 hours prior to your comment).  As to your rules, they are pretty much the standard for golf ("shortest program + input"), but presented more humorously ("pressing buttons is hard!").

Comment: 05AB1E uses windows CP1252, which is bytes, not unicode. I'm aiming for standard rules, but I get told I'm wrong all the time.

Comment: No bonus points for having Go generate some Java? :P

Comment: You can have -10 bytes if you use go:generate ;)

Comment: Most of us spent extra characters to reproduce the code _and_ formatting. Then you post your own answer where you just use some `\t` for indentation. You could specify that from the beginning.

Comment: Woops, my bad, @manatwork . Will change that when I get back home. It should be spaces! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Dennis trailing spaces are removed, and should never have been there in the first place.

Comment: @manatwork My answer should now be correct. Please check for yourself :)

Comment: Thanks @FilipHaglund, now the expectations are more clearly set.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 15):

## PostgreSQL, 158 characters

```sql
select'public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
   '||string_agg(' input == 1'||repeat('0',x)||'L','
  ||')||';
}'from generate_series(0,18)x
```

Comment: I have never seen an RDBMS used as a code golf answer... sweet! +1

Comment: @ChrisCirefice SQL is actually somewhat common on this site. (Or at least more common than one might expect.)

Comment: @AlexA. Hm, well PCG is one of my less-frequented SE sites, so I've never seen a SQL answer :)

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, 52 characters

```
YA#_(""f&bY7#b:c~
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=WUEjXygi8JCAkfKAurjzhpqc8biOn_Gcj5Pxno2B8pufr_OppbDzvpCa8om0jfSNvK_wub6a8raXnPKzma_zraeQ8bm3nPGKvYXwuI-Y8rSCg_Kml6nzp6Wu8KSgkPCwkYjytoKk8JiPp_OUhqfyh4Or86GAvfKKoJHxiqmt8q-QmfGbjLLxipqp8KSxtvC7uqIiZiZiWTcjYjpjfg&input=)

#### Stage 1

Using Unicode characters U+10000 to U+10FFFF, we can encode 20 bits in a single character. CJam uses 16-bit characters internally, so each one will be encoded as a pair of [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates), one in the range from U+D800 to U+DBFF, followed by one in the range from U+DC00 to U+DFFF.

By taking the bitwise AND of each surrogate with 1023, we obtain the 10 bits of information it encodes. We can convert the resulting array from base 1024 to base 128 to decode an arbitrary string of Unicode characters outside the BMP to an ASCII string.

The code does the following:

```
YA#    e# Push 1024 as 2 ** 10.
_(     e# Copy and decrement to push 1023.

""

f&     e# Apply bitwise AND with 1023 to each surrogate character.
b      e# Convert the string from base 1024 to integer.
Y7#    e# Push 128 as 2 ** 7.
b      e# Convert the integer to base 128.
:c     e# Cast each base-128 to an ASCII character.
~      e# Evaluate the resulting string.
```

#### Stage 2

The decoding process from above yields the following source code (**98 bytes**).

```
"public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
   ""L
  || input == ":S6>AJ,f#S*"L;
}"
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=InB1YmxpYyBzdGF0aWMgYm9vbGVhbiBpc1Bvd2VyT2ZUZW4obG9uZyBpbnB1dCkgewogIHJldHVybgogICAiIkwKICB8fCBpbnB1dCA9PSAiOlM2PkFKLGYjUyoiTDsKfSI&input=)

The code does the following:

```
e# Push the following string.

"public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
   "

e# Push the following string and save it in S.

"L
  || input == ":S

e# Discard the first 6 characters of S. The new string begins with " input".

6>

e# Elevate 10 (A) to each exponent below 19 (J).

AJ,f#

e# Join the resulting array, using the string L as separator.

S*

e# Push the following string.

"L;
}"
```

Comment: You might expect a SE site like Judaism to be the ones stress-testing the site's unicode support, but this is crazy :D

Comment: I can see exactly two of the characters between the quote marks. Can you post a hexdump?

Comment: You can actually see two of them? I have no such luck... Encoding the characters as UTF-8, the hexdump would look like this. https://tio.run/nexus/bash#AagAV///eHhkIC1nIDH//1lBI18oIvCQgJHygLq484aanPG4jp/xnI@T8Z6NgfKbn6/zqaWw876QmvKJtI30jbyv8Lm@mvK2l5zys5mv862nkPG5t5zxir2F8LiPmPK0goPyppep86elrvCkoJDwsJGI8raCpPCYj6fzlIan8oeDq/OhgL3yiqCR8YqprfKvkJnxm4yy8YqaqfCksbbwu7qiImYmYlk3I2I6Y34

Answer (score 7):

## Java, <s>217</s> <s>215</s> <s>220</s> <s>219</s> 192 bytes

Golfed:

```
public static String b(){String s="public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return\n    input == 1L",z="";for(int i=0;i++<18;){z+="0";s+="\n  || input == 1"+z+"L";}return s+";\n}";}
```

Ungolfed:

```
  public static String a(){
    String s = "public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return\n    input == 1L", z="";
    for (int i=0; i++ < 18;) {
        z += "0";
        s += "\n  || input == 1"+z+"L";
    }
    return s + ";\n}";
  }
```

(first answer, wuhu)

Thanks!
-2 bytes: user902383
-1 byte: Denham Coote

Changes:

- used tabs instead of spaces
- missed the last line of output: 18 -> 19
- removed inner loop
- changed from printing to returning string

Comment: your inner for loop does not need brackets

Comment: Use Java 8 syntax, also shortened some other stuff: `()->{String s="public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n\treturn input == 1L";for(int i=0,k;i++<18;){s+="\n\t|| input == 1";for(k=0;k++<i;)s+="0";s+="L";}return s+";\n}";}` (180 bytes) Now returns the string instead of printing, but that's shorter.

Comment: +1 for writing a verbose Java program to generate an even more verbose Java program.

Comment: instead of `for(int i=1;i<19;i++)` you can write `for(int i=1;i++<19;)` which saves a byte

Comment: Also, declare  `int i=1,k;` and then you can write `for(;i++<19;)` and `for(k=0;k++<i;)`

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>99</s> <s>97</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> <s>93</s> 87 bytes

Code:

```
“‚Æ£‹ÒŒ€ˆPowerOfTen(“?“¢„î®) {
 «‡
   “?19FN0›i"  ||"?}’ î® == ’?N°?'L?N18Qi';,"}"?}"",
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCc4oCaw4bCo-KAucOSxZLigqzLhlBvd2VyT2ZUZW4o4oCcP-KAnMKi4oCew67CrikgewogwqvigKEKICAg4oCcPzE5Rk4w4oC6aSIgIHx8Ij994oCZIMOuwq4gPT0g4oCZP07CsD8nTD9OMThRaSc7LCJ9Ij99IiIs&input=)

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 7):

## Vim 97 keystrokes

```
ipublic static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
  || input == 1L<esc>qyYpfLi0<esc>q16@yo}<esc>3Gxx
```

Well, I'm on a roll today with vim producing java, so why not continue the trend!

Comment: replacing `fL` with `$` could save you a keystroke

Comment: Also, the third line `input == 1L` is misaligned by one byte...

Comment: So the last `x` should be changed to `r<sp>` and then the number of keystrokes would be unchanged

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell, 120 bytes

```
'public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {'
'  return'
"   $((0..18|%{" input == 1"+"0"*$_})-join"L`n  ||")L;`n}"
```

The first two lines are simply string literals, which are output as-is.

The third line starts with three spaces, and ends with `` L;`n}" `` to finish off the last couple bytes. The middle bit inside the script block `$(...)` is constructed by for-looping `%` from `0` to `18` and each iteration constructing a string that starts with  `input == 1` concatenated with the corresponding number of zeros. This will spit out an array of strings. We then `-join` each element of the array with `` L`n  || `` to achieve the newline-pipes. That big string is the output of the script block, which gets inserted automatically into the middle and output.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\go-generate-some-java.ps1
public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
    input == 1L
  || input == 10L
  || input == 100L
  || input == 1000L
  || input == 10000L
  || input == 100000L
  || input == 1000000L
  || input == 10000000L
  || input == 100000000L
  || input == 1000000000L
  || input == 10000000000L
  || input == 100000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000L
  || input == 10000000000000L
  || input == 100000000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000000L
  || input == 10000000000000000L
  || input == 100000000000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000000000L;
}
```

Comment: A long time ago... :) Very impressive!

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>118</s> <s>106</s> 103 bytes

```
s[."
{Z-L¡JxÙÿ
LæÝ<­í?¢µb'¥ÜA«Ç}h¹äÚÏß"\nb*4dj"\n  || "ms[." uøs|ÀiÝ"*d\0\L)U19\;b\}
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s[.%22%0A%7BZ-L%C2%A1Jx%C3%99%C2%9F%C3%BF%C2%87%06%0A%C2%9BL%C2%8C%C3%A6%C3%9D%3C%C2%AD%C3%AD%3F%C2%A2%C2%B5%07%C2%93b%27%C2%A5%C2%98%C3%9CA%C2%AB%C3%87%7D%0F%12%10h%C2%95%C2%B9%C3%A4%C3%9A%C2%84%C3%8F%C2%86%C3%9F%19%C2%8E%22%5Cnb*4dj%22%5Cn++||+%22ms[.%22+u%01%07%C3%B8%C2%8Es|%C3%80i%C3%9D%22*d%5C0%5CL%29U19%5C%3Bb%5C%7D&debug=0)

All this string hardcoding really eats a lot of bytes up<s>, but nothing I can do about it</s>.

**Update:** Saved 3 bytes by using a packed string. Thanks @user81655 for the hint!

Comment: You could use packed strings...

Comment: I don't know Pyth and I'm not sure if there's a way to pack the full string (the packing program would always alter it) but packing up to `r` and concatenating the `n` results in [this](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5B%2B.%22%0A%7BZ-L%C2%A1Jx%C3%99%C2%9F%C3%BF%C2%87%06%0A%C2%9BL%C2%8C%C3%A6%C3%9D%3C%C2%AD%C3%AD%3F%C2%A2%C2%B5%07%C2%93b%27%C2%A5%C2%98%C3%9CA%C2%AB%C3%87%7D%0F%12%10h%C2%95%C2%B9%C3%A4%C3%9A%C2%84%C3%8F%C2%86%C3%9F%19%C2%8E%22%5Cnb%2a4dj%22%5Cn++%7C%7C+%22ms%5B.%22+u%01%07%C3%B8%C2%8Es%7C%C3%80i%C3%9D%22%2ad%5C0%5CL%29U19%5C%3Bb%5C%7D&debug=0) (98 bytes).

Comment: @user81655 Thanks, didn't know Pyth had this. :) It only makes sense to pack the first big string tho, the overhead you produce form unpacking is not worth it for smaller string.

Comment: @user81655 I am aware of that, but I count 103 characters. How did you get to 97?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I was counting them wrong.

Answer (score 4):

## C# (CSI) <strike>181</strike> <strike>180</strike> 179 byte

```
string i=" input == 1",e="public static bool";Console.Write(e+@"ean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
   "+i+string.Join(@"L
  ||"+i,e.Select((_,x)=>new string('0',x)))+@"L;
}")
```

There is only one little trick involved. The straight forward way to write this would be:

```
string.Join("L\n  || input == 1",Enumerable.Range(0,18).Select(x=>new string('0',x)))
```

by using the string with the first 18 characters of the text which I need anyways I can get rid off the lengthy Enumerable.Range. This works because string implements IEnumerable and there is a  version of Select that hands the item (not needed) and the index which we want to the lambda function.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Thanks

Comment: add some explanation please

Comment: Does CSI support expression bodies? If so, the `{ return ... }` can be replaced by `=>...`.

Comment: Not currently on computer so I can't test this. Does the last verbatim string escape the bracket inside it? Or is it a great trick that I didn't know of? :)

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, <s>172</s> <s>157</s> <s>152</s> <s>150</s> 148 bytes

```
p=>`public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return${[...Array(19)].map((x,i)=>`
  ${i?'||':' '} input == 1${'0'.repeat(i)}L`).join``};
}`
```

```js
f=p=>`public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return${[...Array(19)].map((x,i)=>`
  ${i?'||':' '} input == 1${'0'.repeat(i)}L`).join``};
}`

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + f() + '</pre>'
```

Comment: In ES7 you can save 9 bytes by using `${10**i}` instead of `1${'0'.repeat(i)}`.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>158</s> 155 bytes

```
i;main(){for(puts("public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return");i<19;)printf("  %s input == 1%0.*dL%s\n",i++?"||":" ",i,0,i<18?"":";\n}");}
```

Try it online [here](http://ideone.com/vWyFmE).

Comment: You can shave off a byte if you use the return value of printf:
`i;main(){for(puts("public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return");printf("  %s input == 1%0.*dL%s\n",i++?"||":" ",i,0,i<18?"":";\n}")-37);}`

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, 75 bytes

(These are bytes in Jelly's [custom codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md).)

```
0r18⁵*;@€⁶j“¢œḤḅg^NrÞḢ⁷ẉ»“⁵®UẆƓḃÐL⁴ṖịṛFþẈ¹9}¶ ƁḋȮ¦sẒẆd€Ḟɼ¿ỌṀP^µ\f@»;;“L;¶}”
```

[Try it here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MHIxOOKBtSo7QOKCrOKBtmrigJzCosWT4bik4biFZ15OcsOe4bii4oG34bqJwrvigJzigbXCrlXhuobGk-G4g8OQTOKBtOG5luG7i-G5m0bDvuG6iMK5OX3CtiDGgeG4i8iuwqZz4bqS4bqGZOKCrOG4nsm8wr_hu4zhuYBQXsK1XGZAwrs7O-KAnEw7wrZ94oCd&input=)

#### Explanation

```
0r18      Range [0..18]
⁵*        Take the 10^ of each number
;@€⁶      Prepend a space to each number
j“...»    Join by compressed string "L\n  || input =="
“...»;    Prepend compressed string "public static ... =="
;“L;¶}”   Append "L;\n}"
```

Answer (score 3):

### ES6, <s>139</s> 138 bytes

```js
document.write(`<pre>${(

_=>"0".repeat(19).replace(/./g,`
 || input == 1$\`L`).replace(`
 ||`,`public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
  `)+`;
}`

)()}</pre>`);
```

I do so love these triangle generation questions. Note: Snippet includes header and footer, but these aren't included in the byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## Vimscript, 120 bytes

Might as well use the right tool for the job.

This assumes that autoindent, etc have not been set.  `^[` and `^M` are escape characters for the `ESC` and `CR` characters respectively.

The `a` macro duplicates the current line and adds a 0 to the copy.
The `:norm` line generates all the boilerplate and the `indent == 1L` line, then uses `a` to create the others.

```
:let @a='yyp$i0^['
:norm ipublic static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {^M  return^M  || input == 1L^[18@a$a;^M}
:3s/||/ /
```

In case the trailing spaces the sample output had on two lines weren't typos, here's a 126 byte version that includes them.

```
:let @a='yyp/L^Mi0^['
:norm ipublic static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {^M  return ^M  || input == 1L^[18@a$a;^M}   
:3s/||/ /
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>125</s> 119 bytes

```ruby
$><<'public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
   '+(0..19).map{|i|" input == #{10**i}L"}*'
  ||'+';
}'
```

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for -6 bytes!

Comment: Not much original as most of the solutions are doing this way, but still shorter: http://pastebin.com/1ZGF0QTs

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 123 characters

(121 characters code + 2 characters command line option.)

```
"public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
   \([range(19)|" input == 1\("0"*.//"")L"]|join("
  ||"));
}"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -nr '"public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
>   return
>    \([range(19)|" input == 1\("0"*.//"")L"]|join("
>   ||"));
> }"'
public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
    input == 1L
  || input == 10L
  || input == 100L
  || input == 1000L
  || input == 10000L
  || input == 100000L
  || input == 1000000L
  || input == 10000000L
  || input == 100000000L
  || input == 1000000000L
  || input == 10000000000L
  || input == 100000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000L
  || input == 10000000000000L
  || input == 100000000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000000L
  || input == 10000000000000000L
  || input == 100000000000000000L
  || input == 1000000000000000000L;
}
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=%22public%20static%20boolean%20isPowerOfTen%28long%20input%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20return%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5C%28[range%2819%29|%22%20input%20==%201%5C%28%220%22*.//%22%22%29L%22]|join%28%22%5Cn%20%20||%22%29%29%3B%5Cn%7D%22&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL 9.2, 311 bytes

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {'||CHR(10)||'  return'||c||';'||'}', 'n  ||', 'n'||CHR(10)||'   '),CHR(10)||';', ';'||CHR(10)) FROM(SELECT LEVEL l,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH('input == '||TO_CHAR(POWER(10,LEVEL-1))||'L'||CHR(10),'  || ')c FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<20)WHERE l=19
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 - <s>130</s> 141

```
@s=map{'input == 1'.0 x$_."L\n  ||"}0..18;$s[$#s]=~s/\n  \|\|/;\n}/g;print"public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input){\n  return\n    @s"
```

EDIT: fixed to have exact indentation

Comment: No need to use parenthesis around the range. In change would be nice to reproduce the exact indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the parenthesis that I forgot. I've fixed it to have the exact indentation.

Comment: There is no need for the `g` flag for the substitution. Also as you have a single `\n` in that string, you can simply match it and everything after it: `$s[$#s]=~s/\n.+/;\n}/`. But a `join` based one would still be shorter: http://pastebin.com/hQ61Adt8

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it would be nice if I just copied and pasted your solution, so I'll just leave it as it is as my own best effort. In time, I'll get better at golfing :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin, <s>194</s> 193 characters

```
fun main(u:Array<String>){var o="public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n\treturn"
var p:Long=1
for(k in 0..18){
o+="\n\t"
if(k>0)o+="||"
o+=" input == ${p}L"
p*=10
}
print("$o;\n}")}
```

Test it at http://try.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf. Nice first answer, but please add a link to an online interpreter or add an example on how to run this program, so others can verify it. However, have a great time here! :)

Answer (score 1):

### Python (3.5) <s>137</s> 136 bytes

```
print("public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return\n   ",'\n  || '.join("input == %rL"%10**i for i in range(19))+";\n}")
```

**Previous version**

```
print("public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return\n   ",'\n  || '.join("input == 1"+"0"*i+"L"for i in range(19))+";\n}")
```

Comment: 135 with Python 2.7: `print "public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return\n    %s;\n}"%"\n  || ".join("input == %r"%10L**i for i in range(19))`

Comment: @moooeeeep you're right, the use of %r win 1 bytes and the python 2 `print` (without parenthesis ) win another one

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 175 bytes

Let's do this regularly

```
var s = "public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n\treturn\n\t\tinput == 1";
for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    s += "\n\t|| input == 1";
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        s += "0";
    }
    s += "L" ;
}
s += ";\n}";
alert(s);
```

Pretty small. Now, some javascript magic, like no semicolons needed, or no var's, etc.:

```
k="input == 1"
s="public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n\treturn\n\t\t"+k+"L"
for(i=1;i<20;i++){s+="\n\t|| "+k
for(j=0;j<i;j++)s+="0";s+="L"}s+=";\n}"
alert(s)
```

Comment: Can you explain how that *magic* works? :)

Comment: Javascript doesn't care about semicolons, at least until the keywords (for, while, var, etc.) aren't "touching" anything else. Also, if you don't use the var keyword, you get global variables, wich is the worst feature I have ever seen in a programming language thus far.

Comment: @Bálint. Why this would be the _worst feature_?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes You know, most languages remind you if you misstyped something inside a function. Because javascript takes that as if you made a whole new variable, it does not going to say anything about that.

Comment: Also, same one applies to = returning a true.

Answer (score 0):

### T-SQL <s>289</s>, <s>277</s>, <s>250</s>, 249 bytes

```
SELECT'public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input){return '+STUFF((SELECT'||input=='+N+'L 'FROM(SELECT TOP 19 FORMAT(POWER(10.0,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY id)),'F0')N FROM syscolumns)A FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')+';}'
```

**Update:** Thanks @Bridge, I found a few more spaces too :)

**Update2:** Changed CTE to subquery -27 chars :)
**Update3:** Another space bites the dust @bridge :)

Comment: I was able to trim off 7 more spaces (282 bytes) without changing the rest of the code: `WITH A AS(SELECT CAST('1'AS VARCHAR(20))N UNION ALL SELECT CAST(CONCAT(N,'0')AS VARCHAR(20))FROM A WHERE LEN(N)<20)SELECT'public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input){return '+STUFF((SELECT'|| input=='+N+'L 'FROM A FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 3, '')+';}'`

Comment: Now I look back I can see all the extra spaces in my original comment! I've found one more space you can get rid of - the one immediately after `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 0):

### Java,  210 / 166

Score is depending on whether returning the input from a function meets the definition of 'output'.

Console output (210):

```
class A{public static void main(String[]z){String a=" input == 1",t="L\n  ||"+a,s="public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return\n   "+a;for(int i=0;++i<19;)s+=t+="0";System.out.print(s+"L;\n}");}}
```

String return (166):

```
String a(){String a=" input == 1",t="L\n  ||"+a,s="public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return\n   "+a;for(int i=0;++i<19;)s+=t+="0";return s+"L;\n}";}
```

Legible version:

```
String a() {
    String a=" input == 1", t = "L\n  ||"+a,
        s = "public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return\n   "+a;
    for (int i = 0; ++i < 19;)
        s += t += "0";
    return s + "L;\n}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## ANSI-SQL, 252 characters

```sql
WITH t as(SELECT '   'x,1 c,1 l UNION SELECT'  ||',c*10,l+1 FROM t WHERE l<19)SELECT 'public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {'UNION ALL SELECT'  return 'UNION ALL SELECT x||' input == '||c||'L'||SUBSTR(';',1,l/19)FROM t UNION ALL SELECT'}   ';
```

Ungolfed:

```sql
WITH t as (SELECT '   ' x,1 c,1 l UNION
           SELECT '  ||',c*10,l+1 FROM t WHERE l<19)
SELECT 'public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {' UNION ALL
SELECT '  return ' UNION ALL
SELECT x||' input == '||c||'L'||SUBSTR(';',1,l/19) FROM t UNION ALL
SELECT '}   ';
```

Not a serious attempt, just poking at the Oracle SQL/T-SQL entries.

Comment: For 40 additional chars I can add "from dual " and make it an "Oracle SQL" entry.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (Node.js), 156 bytes

```
s="public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n  return "
for(i=1;i<1e19;i*=10)s+="\n  "+(i-1?"||":" ")+" input == "+i+"L"
console.log(s+";\n}   \n")
```

The `i-1` will only be 0 (and thus falsey) on the very first round (it's just slightly shorter than `i!=1`.

Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5, 137 bytes

Not based on the previous Perl answer, but it is somehow shorter. I believe it can be shortened down again by taking care of the first "input" inside the loop, but I didn't try anything yet (at work atm)

```
$i="input";for(1..18){$b.="  || $i == 1"."0"x$_."L;\n"}print"public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long $i) {\n  return\n    $i == 1L;\n$b}"
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 112 chars

```
"public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
    input == 1"19,"0"a19*.*"L
  || input == 1"*"L;
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, <s>230</s> <s>208</s> <s>206</s> 205 bytes

```
@echo off
echo public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
echo   return
set m=input == 1
echo    %m%L
for /l %%a in (1,1,17)do call:a
call:a ;
echo }
exit/b
:a
set m=%m%0
echo  ^|^| %m%L%1
```

Edit: Saved 22 bytes by avoiding repeating `input ==` and reusing the subroutine for the line with the extra semicolon. Saved <s>2</s> 3 bytes by removing unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Do you need spaces around `==`?

Comment: @Pavel That's not code; it's part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

### AWK+shell, 157 bytes

```
echo 18|awk '{s="input == 1";printf"public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {\n return\n    "s"L";for(;I<$1;I++)printf"\n  ||%sL",s=s"0";print";\n}"}'
```

The question did say to count everything you would have to type.
This does have the added bonus of being able to select how many lines would be placed in the isPowersOfTen method when the boss inevitably changes his mind.

Comment: Passing a here-string is shorter than piping from `echo`: `awk '…'<<<18`

Comment: I knew about here-file but not here-string. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 185 bytes

#### Golfed

```
options(scipen=999);p=paste;cat(p("public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {"," return",p(sapply(0:19,function(x)p(" input == ",10^x,"L",sep="")),collapse="\n ||"),"}",sep="\n"))
```

#### Ungolfed

```
options(scipen=999)
p=paste
cat(
  p("public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {",
        " return",
        p(sapply(0:19,function(x)p(" input == ",10^x,"L",sep="")),collapse="\n ||"),
        "}",
        sep="\n")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6 (115 bytes)

```
say "public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) \{
  return
   {join "L
  ||",(" input == "X~(10 X**^19))}L;
}"
```

`X` operator does list cartesian product operation, for example `10 X** ^19` gives powers of ten (from 10 to the power of 0 to 19, as `^` is a range operator that counts from 0). Strings can have code blocks with `{` (which is why I escape the first instance of it).

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 125 bytes

```sh
P="public static boolean isPowerOfTen(long input) {
  return
   ${1= input == 1}L"
repeat 18 {1+=0;P+="
  ||$1L";}
<<<$P";
}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCgIhFED3nuLzcVHMJneB/hsM5KILOGEliIqjBDme3YRW78F73/09hiZMdfPuAXsxZWKL0VsTwO06fmy@Pe82nHwML3Ah1XKGxgCyLTWHKcCboH8BIhB9RZZtsqaAuEITC12kXgjnehxcrCg7U0pxjZJ1HOMH)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 71 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
18Ý°'L«“  ||î® == “ì”„‡€‚—¿”á
“‚Æ£‹ÒŒ€ˆÿ(ƒÈî®) {
 „Á“š»…;
}«„( ¬:„||ð.;
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0OLw3EMb1H0OrX7UMEdBoabm8LpD6xRsbRWA3MNrHjXMfdQw71HDwkdNQPasRw1TDu0Hih1eyAWUBgocbju0@FHDzsOTjk4Cqjjddni/xrFJhztAZmgqVHMBDZl3uBGo9OjCQ7sfNSyz5qoF2TNPQ@HQGisgDbRtg571//8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
18Ý                      # Push a list in the range [0,18]
   °                     # Take 10^n of each value in this list
    'L«                 '# Append an "L" to each integer
       “  ||î® == “ì     # Prepend dictionary string "  || input == " to each
”„‡€‚—¿”                 # Push dictionary string "Power Of One"
        á                # Only keep the letters / remove the spaces: "PowerOfOne"
“‚Æ£‹ÒŒ€ˆÿ(ƒÈî®) {\n „Á“ # Push dictionary string "public static boolean isÿ( long input) {\n  return",
                         # were the `ÿ` is automatically filled with the "PowerOfOne" string
    š                    # Prepend it in front of the earlier list
     »                   # Join the list by newlines
…;\n}«                   # Append ";\n}" at the end
„(                       # Push string "( "
   ¬                     # Push its first character (without popping): "("
    :                    # Replace the "( " with "("
„||ð.;                   # Replace the first "||" with " "
                         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“  ||î® == “` is `"  || input == "`; `”„‡€‚—¿”` is `Power Of One`; and `“‚Æ£‹ÒŒ€ˆÿ(ƒÈî®) {\n „Á“` is `"public static boolean isÿ( long input) {\n  return"`.